# Calling subprocess.checkoutput() in EXE pyinstaller

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller

I am trying to merge multiple tiff files into one multi-band tiff using python.
I used subprocess.checkoutput('python gdal.merge.py') and it was working well. Then I tried to transform this code to an EXE using pyinstaller, it returns an error. the error is that python was not found.
This is the code I used

```
basename = '*'
outdir2 = './TIFF_Files'
filelist2 = glob.glob(os.path.join(outdir2, basename))
files_string = " ".join(filelist2)
print(files_string)
Tiff_output = os.path.join(outdir2,'Multi_band.tif')
command = "python gdal_merge.py -o " + Tiff_output + " -of gtiff -separate " + files_string
output = subprocess.check_output(command)
```

the error of the EXE is the following :

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Miscrosoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings
```

Can you help me with this. keep in mind that I am not really advanced in python so I apologize if I made an obvious mistake. Thanks

Comment: Unless you are specifically asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed them both.

Comment: Obviously your Pyinstaller script doesn't know it should package the GDAL library. A much better solution anyway is to not call `python` as a subprocess of itself; instead, `import` the GDAL library and call it directly. Then Pyinstaller will know to include that library in the exe, too. (Not sure if it will still work, though; apparently you will need to include the GDAL binaries too.)

Comment: Can you explain how to include the GDAL library and binaries as well as how to call the merge function? thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with Pyinstaller or GDAL; but it should be obvious that if you call an external process, that binary needs to be installed on the destination computer. If you call a Python library which requires DLLs etc in order to work, those will similarly need to be installed first.

Comment: I understand. I tried looking for another way to merge tiff files without the external process but I could not find it. I don't know how I can use GDAL library to do so. Can you suggest a way for that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "merging" TIFF files but if it's a general image processing step, I would imagine Pillow should be able to do it.

Comment: If you mean stitch them together side by side, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pillow/Python_pillow_merging_images.htm seems to do that.

Comment: I mean the mosaic process. I have multiple tiff files representing the same area and I want to turn them into one tiff file that has multiple bands.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to replace the external process by using rasterio.

```
filelist2 = glob.glob(os.path.join(outdir2, basename))

# Read metadata of first file
with rasterio.open(filelist2[0]) as src0:
    meta = src0.meta

# Update meta to reflect the number of layers
meta.update(count = len(filelist2))

# Read each layer and write it to stack
Tiff_output = os.path.join(outdir2,'Multi_band.tif')
with rasterio.open(Tiff_output, 'w', **meta) as dst:
    for id, layer in enumerate(filelist2, start=1):
        with rasterio.open(layer) as src1:
            dst.write_band(id, src1.read(1))
```

outdir2 is the directory of the tiff files and basename = '*.tif'
Using this method, Pyinstaller worked perfectly